# processing more than one xhtml file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have two xhtml input files  and need one xhtml output file using xslt. how to achieve with xslt?.

Please help me

thanks

Comment: What is the nature of the combination?
If your combining the contents this should ideally be done before you translate!

Comment: example here for merging xml in a similar fashion

http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/xslt/document/

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: i have some info in one input file and second input have some other information, so finally i have to make one file with XSLT

Comment: Input1.xhtml
<html>
<table>...</table>
</html>

Input2.xhtml
<html>
<table>....</table>
</html>
now i have to use the above two sample inputs and generate one output file(as shown below) using xslt.
output file:
<html>
<table>...</table>
<table>...</table>
</html>

Please help me on this. 
thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first file is used as usual, while the second (and any more) can be used via the XPath command "document()" directly or as a variable. The variable solution looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:variable name="file2" select="document('file2.xhtml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Use 2 input files</title>
        </head>
            <body>
                <p>File 1 <xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
                <p>File 2 <xsl:value-of select="$file2"/></p>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course you have to complete "value-of select=" to point to the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Using the XSLT [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document) function it is possible to work with (process) many XML documents by a single XSLT transformation**.